# Utilizing Google Talk plugin in a web app

Tags: javascript, webrtc, google-talk, video-conferencing

Does anyone know if the Google Talk browser plugin can be used by web application developers? I'm talking about manipulating it with HTML/JavaScript. The Google Talk dev site only seems to have information for developers who want to develop independent client/server apps. But theres nothing about utilizing the embedded plugin used by gmail, igoogle and orkut (apparently).

I'm particularly interested in using the audio/video conferencing capabilities; possibly with non-Google libjingle servers. I'm guessing Google didn't publish the API for competitive reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this is possible however, there is a project to bring these capabilities to browsers.  It is called [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/). It looks like it is available in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Thanks. This is actually better than using their plugin.